# Replace crHourGlass with the new Windows 7 "snake eating its tail" cursor

Tags: delphi

My Delphi XE2 apps look a bit dated these days because they use:

```
 Screen.Cursor := crHourglass;
```

Is there a way to change the cursor to the the more modern looking rotating "snake eating its tail" icon that Windows uses?

Other than this [Am I restricted to the cursor numbers defined in Controls.pas under Delphi 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122128/am-i-restricted-to-the-cursor-numbers-defined-in-controls-pas-under-delphi-7) I haven't been able to find anything on SO or Google that addresses this.

Snake eating its tail cursor preview:

[image: snake eating its tail cursor]

Comment: But on Windows 7 the `crHourglass` looks like you've described.

Comment: It also does using Delphi XE. I thought it might be an issue with themes, but it's correct with or without runtime themes enabled.

Comment: What version of Windows are you trying this on?

Comment: What is "“snake eating its tail” cursor"?

Comment: @Pol - I had to look it up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros

Comment: Warren guesses that Robert is running on XP. That would explain everything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "not a real question" since the code you provide already gives the effect you desire.

Comment: You'll get the old style cursors if you are running under the Windows Classic theme. Or if you are using XP.

Comment: @David - You are correct. This is a Windows theme issue. Thank you.

If you post your comment as an answer, I'll flag it as such.

Comment: @TLama: I upvoted your comment in appreciation of your adding the animation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different Windows schemes have different cursors. If you are using one of the Aero schemes then you will see the cursors to which you refer. If you are using, for example, Windows Classic, then you will see the older XP style cursors.

```
Screen.Cursor := crHourglass;
```

is all you need to do to show the currently active scheme's busy cursor.

Comment: +1 for spotting the *real* problem.

Comment: David: you continue to amaze us with your prolific & insightful postings and your deep knowledge on such a broad range of topics. 

From all of us in our SO Delphi community: THANKS for your enormous contributions.

Comment: @Robert Well thanks, but I'm not sure there was a lot of insight here, just a lucky guess. In fact Warren's comment and philnext's answer were the inspiration for that guess. Without those contributions I would have had no hope of making that lucky guess.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the crHourGlass is a 'wrapper' to the 'busy' Windows cursor. 
You may change it 'manually' in your system 'Mouse' control panel :configure your 'Pointer' settings from the model you want.

Comment: -1. This is absolutely not needed. `Screen.Cursor := crHourglass;` does exactly what is needed, and no manual configuration in Control Panel is necessary.

Comment: @Ken I think that philnext knows this. I suspect that he/she means that the system wide cursor configuration on Robert's machine may not be the default Windows 7 cursors. I don't know, perhaps if Windows Classic is used then you get the old style XP cursors.

Comment: @David, it could well be, but the answer doesn't mention themes or anything remotely related. It's simply a statement that it can be changed in CP. It isn't an answer; it might be a fine comment as a suggestion to the original question. ("Are you using any custom settings for the mouse pointer? How about Windows Classic mode?".) (Robert really should read the responses he's getting here and update the question, but he hasn't so far apparently.)

Comment: +1 to counter the -1 from someone who seems to have misunderstood every word he read.